# How can I find my deleted questions?

Tags: support, questions, deleted-questions

There are badges that require a "positive question record", and [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234259/asking-days-badges) gives the following way of calculating whether you have such a record.

```
(total questions - negative questions - closed - deleted)/total questions >= 0.5
```

I'm having trouble reconciling this, however, as I can't actually find records for my deleted questions.

- **Total questions:** I'm guessing this includes not just the total of the questions listed on your profile, but also deleted ones. In my case, at the time this was written my RPG account has 7 questions on record, but I know there was a question that was deleted in the past. However; *I can't see this anywhere*. 
  **There is a link to click for "deleted recent questions"** but this only contains questions less than 60 days old, and apparently this question is older than that. If the fact that I can't find it means it doesn't count, **this value is 7**.
- **Negative questions:** I'm not exactly sure what makes a question negative, but my best guess is it's "A question that has more down votes than up votes against it." By this definition I have one negative question on record now. While the deleted question was almost certainly negative, if I can't find it I can't verify/count **which leaves only a value of 1**.
- **Closed questions:** Again, because the deleted question was (I'm pretty sure) closed first, it may count, but I can't find it **so this should be 2**.
- **Deleted questions:** The whole point of this question - I can't find it to count it, or even verify that there are no further deleted questions.

From memory I believe the question that was deleted was negative and was first closed, so my calculation should be:

```
(7-1-1-0)/7=0.714 without the deleted question and
(8-2-2-1)/8=0.375 with the deleted question accounted for.
```

I still don't qualify, so the second one is right. **If this is how it's calculated, shouldn't I be able to access/verify records of deleted questions?**

Comment: Related feature request on MSE: [Show all of my question/answers to me even if they are deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2645/153219)

Comment: True. Maybe that question needs to be re-posed, as it's ***7 years old!!!*** and possibly the rulings are as well...

Comment: Reposting would just get it marked as a duplicate. But it’s worth noting that the “recent deleted posts” link is relatively new and a step towards that feature request, now that some old problems with being able to access deleted posts (like undeleting them when you shouldn’t be able to) have been fixed. So there’s evidence it’s evolving…

Comment: Yeah, if it wasn't evolving it wouldn't matter that the question is old! :P
I wouldn't suggest re-posting for exactly that reason. That's why I used the word "re-posed" as I did, though perhaps "revisited" would be a clearer term.

Answer (score 4):

As the other 2 answers have already mentioned you can find your most recently deleted questions by going to your profile's "activity" tab, selecting "questions", scrolling to the bottom and clicking the link that says "deleted recent questions". This, however, only works for questions deleted in the past 60 days.

There is *one* other way to view your own deleted question but it requires at least **10k** rep. As discussed on [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/145060) Meta Stack question you can input `deleted:1` into the search bar and it will show you your deleted content.

Comment: I was worried that was the case... It seems to me like if there are milestones we can chase that are based on this data we should have access to it... In my case I have one deleted question (though possibly two in 60 days time...) but if people have a few, it could be very difficult to keep track of them once they disappear...

Comment: It's a fair point that "your" data that's important for things we've badged as important should be available to you. Feel free to ping me or another mod in [chat] and it'd be easy enough to dig up for you your numbers. I suppose I'll have to rescind the invitation if we end up overwhelmed by research requests, but for now I'll risk it =)

Comment: @nitsua60 cool, cool, that's one way to do it. I suppose it doesn't seem *super* likely that *too* many people will want to track this info at any one time...

Answer (score 0):

I can see deleted questions in my profile, I guess it may be a rep thing.  Anyway, your one deleted question on main is https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/123382/is-there-a-tabletop-system-with-space-combat-integrated-or-will-we-need-to-home

Comment: I can use the method described in [A_Soo's answer](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8215/43956) but it won't show the post in question as it's too old. Is that the method you're talking about?

Comment: Mods can See All.

Answer (score 0):

I can access mine by:

- Going to my profile
- Clicking on the "Activity" tab
- Selecting "Questions"
- Scrolling down to the bottom
- Clicking the link in the bottom-left that says "Deleted Recent Questions," [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDTgW.png)

For you, this should lead to:  https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/43956

However, I'm not sure whether this is rep-locked, as mxy [speculates](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8214/30299), nor am I sure what exactly constitutes "recent" (do sufficiently old deleted questions not appear here?).

Comment: Yes, sufficiently old deleted questions don't appear there. It used to be there, but no longer is.